# how to increase custom count in jquery json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If laptop model and serial id are same, i've to add new field totalModel and increase count. For example in below case: serialid "1" and laptop model "xyz" are coming two time so i want to add "totalModel" count as 2 and so on. How can i achieve this in jquery

Comment: What would the result be if the two "xyz" laptopModel objects had different values for 'sold'?

Comment: Value remain same as per our data.. so no need to worry about 'sold'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not really about jQuery, it is about mapping and filtering arrays and objects. However, we can use some jQuery convenience methods to solve it.

A large part of solving these problems is by properly defining what you want to do. It sounds from your question that you want to get a map of unique serial ids per laptop model type. We can use JavaScript's Array.prototype.reduce to produce just such a map (Note that we will take the 'sold' value for the first of each laptop model we encounter):

```
var laptop_models = data.reduce(function (memo, obj) {
    if (!memo[obj.laptopModel]) {
        memo[obj.laptopModel] = {
            unique_serial_ids: [],
            sold: obj.sold
        };
    }

    if ($.inArray(obj.serialid, memo[obj.laptopModel].unique_serial_ids) === -1) {
        memo[obj.laptopModel].unique_serial_ids.push(obj.serialid);
    }

    return memo;
}, {});
```

Next, we can map our `laptop_models` object into the array you specified as your expected result:

```
var result = $.map(laptop_models, function (laptop_model, model_name) {
    return {
        laptopModel: model_name,
        totalModel: laptop_model.unique_serial_ids.length,
        sold: laptop_model.sold
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
          {
            "serialid": 1,
            "laptopModel": "xyz",
            "sold": "yes",
            "cnt": 5
          },
          {
            "serialid" :1,
            "laptopModel": "xyz",
            "sold": "yes",
            "cnt": 4
          },
          {
            "serialid": 1,
            "laptopModel": "abc",
            "sold": "yes",
            "cnt": 3
          },
          {
            "serialid": 3,
            "laptopModel": "xyz",
            "sold": "yes",
            "cnt": 2
          }];



var result = []; //work if result = {};
var tempArray = []; // used to store unique name to prevent complex loop
data.forEach(function(item){
      if($.inArray(item.laptopModel, tempArray)< 0){// unique name
          result.push(formatData(item));
          tempArray.push(item.laptopModel);
        }
  else{
       var indexNew =  $.inArray(item.laptopModel, tempArray); 
       result[indexNew]["totalModel"] += 1;
     }
  });

function formatData(item){
 return{
    "laptopModel": item.laptopModel,
    "sold": item.sold,
    "totalModel": 1
   }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result)); //expect array 2 item but it's empty array
console.log(result); //Will have result 2 item when I view console window
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks bipashant! Seems like my question was confused you I've edited the question again... the way I'm looking i mentioned above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jquerybeginner I updated by answer. Hope this will work as you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks again! I don't want add the **cnt** count in anyplace - take out from the logic.. I want to check the laptop model with unique serial id -- In my cae serialid 1 and serialId 3 having laptop model **xyz** that means **totalModel** count should come 2 .. again serialId 1 contains laptop model **abc** only once so totalModel count should come for this scneario is 1.

Comment: Thanks again :) Almost same but one small change the expected result is [
    {

        "laptopModel": "xyz",
        "sold": "yes",
        "totalModel": 2
    },
    {
        "laptopModel": "abc",
        "sold": "yes",
        "totalModel": 1
    }
]  because serialid 1 contains laptop model **xyz** twice that means we should consider totalModel count as 1 but in your scenario your considering twice

Answer (score 0):

You got the idea already.   Iterate through the array.
if them item is in a hash, increment the count, otherwise, add to the hash and set the count to 1

```
var hash = {};
for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
  if (hash[data[i].laptopModel) {
     hash[data[i].laptopModel]++;
  }
  else
     hash[data[i].laptopModel] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I want to add new field called **totalModel** and I want to increase the count of this one...